# How to convert Bigquery repeated record into a column?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, unnest

`event_params` is a repeated record. Its key values can be
`firebase_event_origin`, `engagement_time_msec`, `firebase_screen`, ...

Each key has a number of optional values according to the data type:
`string_value`, `int_value`, ...
I want to convert the *key* into a column and that the *value* will populate it.

For example: the key `firebase_screen` will be converted into a column `firebase_screen` with a value of `webview screen`. Same for all the other repeated records in the table.
I'm not sure if the `UNNEST` is the right solution here since it breaks it down into records instead of columns.

The screenshots of schema and the table I used for this example:

[image: schema]
[image: table]

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest first, then group the data again.

Please replace the bracket in `FROM ( ... )`  with your table.

```
SELECT
  date,
  ANY_VALUE(CASE WHEN t.key="firebase_screen" THEN t.string_value ELSE NULL END) AS firebase_screen,
  ANY_VALUE(CASE WHEN t.key="ga_session_number" THEN t.int_value ELSE NULL END) AS ga_session_number,
FROM (
  SELECT
    1 date,
    [STRUCT("firebase_screen" AS key,
      "webs" AS string_value,
      NULL AS int_value),
    STRUCT("ga_session_number" AS key,
      NULL,
      6 AS int_value) ] AS event_params ) AS tbl,
  UNNEST(tbl.event_params) AS t
GROUP BY  1
```